# Pixel 3 help Android

Tags: android

Ok This might seem like a dumb question but I'm not finding an answer.

I use to program for my old samsung S3.  It's basically the device I learned to code for because it was all I had.  But all the coding I was doing was old code I learned off Youtube etc.. as I'm self taught.

I recently invested in myself to learn some more modern code and to do things I couldn't do with my old equipment and I have run into trouble.

I have managed to fix some things like my retrofit and Picasso not working, because of a line of code missing in the manifest, but I am stuck when it comes to the Camera app as my code doesn't work on my pixel 3 but does work on my S3.

So I have a few questions that maybe someone can help answer for me.

so my 1st question is involving saving my pictures.

```
 private File getfile () throws IOException {
    File propicturefolder = new File("sdcard/camera_pro");
    if (!propicturefolder.exists())
    {
        propicturefolder.mkdir();
    }

    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String prepend = "Picture_" + timestamp + "_";
    File image_file = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".jpg", propicturefolder);
    return image_file;
}
```

As you can see in my first bit of code I'm saving the picture to the SD card.  But apparently a Pixel 3 doesn't have a SD card.  So I don't know where to save it?  There aren't really any examples out there that explain where this goes for a pixel 3.  All my old examples go to the SD card.
I have tried to google an answer for this but nothing comes up but reviews of the Pixel 3 camera.  What is the correct path that I am suppose to use?

My second question is this.
On my S3 I don't have to really ask for any permissions other than in the manifest so I'm trying to understand how this whole permission thing works.  In the Manifest I have.

```
     <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true" />
```

But in some of the example I am looking to learn permissions I see.

```
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Am I suppose to use both of these?  I had learned Camera is outdated and Camera2 is what is used.  Should that be android.permission.CAMERA2?
My camera doesn't work on my Pixel 3 but the code does work on my S3.  So I need to learn how to code this differently apparently.
Google doesn't really give great examples on any of this.  And the web is simply flooded with a lot of the wrong way to do things aka old ways.
If anyone can explain to me the changes on how this works on API 28 so I can learn how to add the slow motion camera etc or point me to an example that isn't out dated and made for android api 28 your help would be appreciated.

Comment: your first question seems like you haven't tried anything yet and speaking of camera2 google does provide complete github repository with atleast all basic functionalities. You can find tons of tutorial for check if sd card is available on device or not and if not then save it to internal storage

Comment: I have looked, I get the whole internal storage thing as that is the only other place it can go.  But I don't know the path.  What is the internal storage path suppose to look like. Is it suppose to be  /storage/(myDirectory).  I don't want to simply be dumping files in and screw something else up.

Comment: You don't need to hardcode path like that in your code. You can simply pass `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path of the internal storage

Comment: ok so then that line should look like such.  File propicturefolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());  thank you for your help on that.

Comment: yes and remember to give permissions in manifest

Comment: hmm which permission do I give.  Is it. uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" or uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" since it's looking for external Storage Directory.

Comment: external storage

Comment: ok thank you, sorry for the late reply.  I had to work.  It's the busy season with the holiday and all.